# Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4200/contacts/styles.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME[...]

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing

I am developing a test app to follow an online course.

Now I wanted to use the route params and so my code is like this:

In app.routing.module.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LandingComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent},
    { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent},
    { path: 'contacts/:id', component: ContactDetailComponent},
    { path: 'prezzi', component: PrezziComponent}
]
```

and here comes the issue:

if I use the path: 'contactsId', ContactDetailComponent is loaded

if I use the path: 'contacts/id' or 'contacts/:id' and try to reach 'contacts/id' in the first case or, for instance, contacts/Pippo in the second, the console throw this error:

```
p://localhost:4200/contacts/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
Pippo:32 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:4200/contacts/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Pippo:32 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:4200/contacts/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Pippo:32 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:4200/contacts/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Pippo:32 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:4200/contacts/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Pippo:32 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:4200/contacts/styles.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Pippo:1  Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4200/contacts/styles.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

why?

---

solved inserting this in index.html